# Set Eclipse PHP debugger to xDebug

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I was following [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZfILDk__1o&index=4&list=PL5eQ8OiXq2PpfreXkOpno_21yY5U7qsiV) to setup xDebug on Eclipse. When I go into Preference, there is no Dropdown menu for me to select xDebug in the debugger field (See below):[image]

Here is what I have in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = ON
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

From my installed debugger, XDebug is there too.
[image]

Might anyone know what the problem is??